# Is it possible to emit dynamic data to an animation made in flare from some language like javascript / flutter / dart?

Tags: flare

I am new to the topic and I am exploring this tool, but I have not seen any way to output data within an animation already made in flare.

From some programming language such as javascript, flutter or dart, I would like to do the following: the user writes his name in a text field. I previously have an animation made in flare and at a certain moment of the animation I want to put the name that the user has entered in this animation made in flare.
for example I have the animation of a person showing a cell phone, I would like to put the text entered at a certain point in this animation.

[image]

I am relying on this animation:

https://rive.app/a/JuanCarlos/files/flare/filip/preview

Is this possible to do?